# dissociated variables in array

Tags: php, variables, silex

I have a problem with php variables. I use a code that looks like this:

```
for($i = 0; $i <= $nbRecurrence; $i++) {  
    $res = new Reservation();  
    $res->setDateDebut($DateDebut->add(new \DateInterval('P1D')));
    $res->setDateFin($DateFin->add(new \DateInterval('P1D')));
    $lesRes[] = $res;
    $this->app['orm.ems']['gestionReservationAuto']->persist($res);
    $this->app['orm.ems']['gestionReservationAuto']->flush();
}
```

The problem is that although I adds each element in the array, but when I use a `var_dump` for analysis, all `$res` in `$lesRes` are identical. Registered data is yet different in the database ...

How can I do to have an array with `$res` that do not like?

(if I make a request to have the items I just added in database, I have the same problem, I have an array of x elements `$res`, which are all identical.)

Comment: it's because in each iterration you are creating new Reservation object and you append same data (from $DateDebut and $DateFin objects) to them, thats why they are identical, if you got those reservations in database just query them from database first, and by the way what are those objects $DateDebut and $DateFin ?

Comment: Just for clarification, you are creating completely different and unique Reservation instances in each iteration. But all of your Reservation objects contain the same data. So, not a problem of instanciation or referencing but simply with using the same data.

Comment: Why the downvote? And why closing? Maybe the question is not very well expressed but the problem it presents is something that a lot of people overlook and get confused when the things starts behaving strange.

Comment: @user1716552 it's not clear from the question: is the data stored correctly in the database? I mean, don't use your code to read it, use a MySQL client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess `$DateDebut` is a `DateTime` object.
I also guess that `Reservation::setDateDebut()` looks something like:

```
class Reservation
{
    private $dateDebut;

    public function setDateDebut(DateTime $dateDebut)
    {
        $this->dateDebut = $dateDebut;
    }
}
```

And let's write again the code that uses it:

```
$res = new Reservation();  
$res->setDateDebut($DateDebut->add(new \DateInterval('P1D')));
```

What you miss is the fact that `DateTime::add()` does not create a new `DateTime` object but returns a reference to the current object (i.e. `return $this;`).

This means on each iteration you change the value of object `$DateDebut` then you pass it to `Reservation::setDateDebut()` which also doesn't make a copy of it but just links to the object it gets as argument.

After the loop you still have only two instances of `DateTime`; one of them is accessible through the variable `$DateDebut` and the members `$dateDebut` of all the `Reservation` objects created during the loop. The other instance is `$DateFin` and the same discussion is valid for it too.

Your code is a victim of [variables aliasing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing_%28computing%29).

#### How to fix it:

You need to create copies of `$DateDebut` somewhere, either in the loop code (and pass the copies to `Reservation::setDateDebut()`) or in the body of `Reservation::setDateDebut()`:

```
// Either
$res->setDateDebut(clone $DateDebut->add(new \DateInterval('P1D')));


// Or
public function setDateDebut(DateTime $dateDebut)
{
    $this->dateDebut = clone $dateDebut;
}
```

You decide where is the most appropriate place to do it, depending how the rest of the code works with these objects.

Because you change the value of `$DateDebut` in the loop you should make copies of the object there.

If the class `Reservation` changes the value of its `$dateDebut` member then you should (also) clone it in the setter method. This is because the caller of `Reservation::setDateDebut()` does not expect the `Reservation` class make changes on the value it passes as an argument.